# Problema com decisão dentro do loop de um array

Tags: java

Meu problema está no segundo if, o que na verdade eu estava tentando fazer era determinar para que no momento em que o loop estivesse passando pela posição 11 do array ele adicionasse o "\n", porém da forma que fiz, ele faz isso em todos os loops, não somente na posição que desejo. Já entendi meu erro, mas não sei como fazê-lo corretamente.

```
  package gerarOrganizar;
  import java.util.*;
  //import java.util.Arrays;
  //import java.util.Collections;
  //import java.util.Random;
  import static javax.swing.JOptionPane.*;
  public class GerarOrganizar {


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Integer[] array = new Integer[20];
        Random gerador=new Random();
        String aux="";
        for(int i=0;i<20;i++){
            array[i]=gerador.nextInt(50);
            if(array[i]==0)//descarta números = 0
                i--;
        }//for de geração de valores

        aux=String.format("Antes \n");
        for(int i:array){//percorre todo o array retornando o valor para i
            if(array[11]!=null)//este aqui é o problema
                aux=String.format(aux+"\n");
            aux=String.format(aux+"\t %d",i);
    }//fim do for

        showMessageDialog(null,aux);//imprime a ordem gerada

        Arrays.sort(array,Collections.reverseOrder());
        /*sort decide a ordem númerica em ordem decrescente devido ao Collections.reverseOrder*/

        aux=String.format("Depois");
            for(int i:array){/*percorre array retornando os valores para i*/
                aux=String.format(aux+"\n %d",i);/*copia os valor do array na string*/
            }//fim do for

        showMessageDialog(null,aux);//imprime a ordem
    }//main

 }//class
```

Comment: Oi, Adrian, da próxima vez indique a linha com um comentário `// <----------- LINHA 22`. Colocando a numeração aqui faz com que o copy/paste pra testar fique complicado.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Isto acontece porque em todas as interações no ciclo em questão a posição 11 no vetor é diferente de `null`.

Podes resolver da seguinte forma:

```
...
for(int i; i<array.lenght; i++){//percorre todo o array retornando o valor para i
   if( i == 11 ){
         aux=String.format(aux+"\n");
   }
   aux=String.format(aux+"\t %d",array[i]);
}//fim do for
...
```

Comment: Apesar de que em todas as posições a verificação será realizada mesmo que já tenha alcançado a desejada. Isto pode ser melhorado...